# Remove CSS from a Div using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

In my App I have the following:

```
$("#displayPanel div").live("click", function(){
  $(this).css({'background-color' : 'pink', 'font-weight' : 'bolder'});
});
```

When I click on a Div, the color of that Div is changed. Within that Click function I have some functionalities to do. After all that I want to remove the applied Css from the Div. How could I do it in JQuery?

Comment: boy, you've opened a can of worms!

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Put your CSS properties into a class, then do something like this:

```
$("#displayPanel div").live("click", function(){
   $(this).addClass('someClass');
});
```

Then where your 'other functionalities' are do something like:

```
$("#myButton").click(function(){
   $("#displayPanel div").removeClass('someClass');
});
```

Comment: In the head part of your document, put a CSS block like <style type="text/css">#displayPanel div{ background-color:pink;font-weight:bold}</style>

Comment: @Aruna: I'm a little scared now - how *are* you putting the style on the element? If your CSS isn't in a stylesheet/block it's not CSS.

Comment: @annakata: Sure it is... `<div style="xxx"/>` is still CSS... it's not a very good way of doing it, but it does work.

Comment: Wan't ALWAYS override the previous value the element  had.

Comment: This answer doesn't help all the case where you modify something on the fly for doing animation or complex rendering. The question was not about how to organize the CSS, but how to remove a CSS option.

Comment: @FMaz008 - Animation and complex rendering is waay beyond what he asked. Read the question: "...After all that I want to remove the applied Css from the Div". So he could use `addClass` or `removeClass` or `removeAttr('style')` as in @ToRrEs's answer.

Comment: Although below worked for me too I feel this was the best solution seeing as I prefer to do ALL styling or at least as much as possible in my stylesheets. I ended up doing things this way.

Comment: @annakata Yes, it is still CSS. That method of specifying styles is called inline styling. It is common when you are dealing with jQuery. You will get to see lot of styles applied & removed dynamically, depending upon the requirement.

Comment: @Jasmine - removeClass did not work in my case. I tried this  $('#buttonRefresh').css("border-color", ""); and it works for me

Comment: To remove only one css property: var cssObject = `$('selector').prop('style'); cssObject.removeProperty('font-weight');`

Answer (score 308):

You can remove specific css that is on the element like this:

```
$(this).css({'background-color' : '', 'font-weight' : ''});
```

Although I agree with karim that you should probably be using CSS classes.

Comment: That would remove the previous settings for background-color and font-weight

Comment: @Dave worked beautifully in IE7 for me *to remove styles directly applied inline to the element*, not to remove styles applied through css classes.

Comment: The problem is that when setting background to '', IE7 happily adds defaults for all the different background-* properties. Which means that if you have background-* property set otherwise (thru classes, for instance) they get cleared by this. I had to deal with this specific issue in our product.

Comment: Work well for me although I ended up using addClass seeing as styling should be done in stylesheets. I personally like to keep things organised.

Comment: Note that this is NOT the same as $element.css('top', '');, which does not remove the style. You must pass in an object: $element.css({'top: ''});

Answer (score 224):

You could use the removeAttr method, if you want to delete all the inline style you added manually with javascript. It's better to use CSS classes but you never know.

> `$("#displayPanel div").removeAttr("style")`

Comment: This is a better solution than using additional class, +1.

Comment: Good answer - jQuery's `.css('style-name', 'style-value')` function adds inline styles to an element - and is essential for updating styles on the fly. A drag/drop script might change the `top` and `left` styles of an absolutely positioned element - an instance where using classes is impractical.

Comment: It is better than other options as we just need to remove style.

Comment: Just like to add that chrome will not handle this correctly as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192263/unable-to-remove-style-attribute-in-chrome) a safer option would be using `attr('style', '').

Comment: Great answer. As long as you're sure to *only* have inline CSS that you *want* removed once this is executed (as is often the case for animations), then this is the way to go.

Answer (score 40):

You can remove inline properties this way:

```
$(selector).css({'property':'', 'property':''});
```

For example:

```
$(actpar).css({'top':'', 'opacity':''});
```

This is essentially mentioned above, and it definitely does the trick.

BTW, this is useful in instances such as when you need to clear a state after animation. Sure I could write a half dozen classes to deal with this, or I could use my base class and #id do some math, and clear the inline style that the animation applies.

```
$(actpar).animate({top:0, opacity:1, duration:500}, function() {
   $(this).css({'top':'', 'opacity':''});
});
```

Comment: just something I was looking for, removes the inline styles.. thanks

Answer (score 12):

```
jQuery.fn.extend
({
    removeCss: function(cssName) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var curDom = $(this);
            jQuery.grep(cssName.split(","),
                    function(cssToBeRemoved) {
                        curDom.css(cssToBeRemoved, '');
                    });
            return curDom;
        });
    }
});

/*example code: I prefer JQuery extend so I can use it anywhere I want to use.

$('#searchJqueryObject').removeCss('background-color');
$('#searchJqueryObject').removeCss('background-color,height,width'); //supports comma separated css names.

*/
```

OR

```
//this parse style & remove style & rebuild style. I like the first one.. but anyway exploring..
jQuery.fn.extend
({
    removeCSS: function(cssName) {
        return this.each(function() {

            return $(this).attr('style',

            jQuery.grep($(this).attr('style').split(";"),
                    function(curCssName) {
                        if (curCssName.toUpperCase().indexOf(cssName.toUpperCase() + ':') <= 0)
                            return curCssName;
                    }).join(";"));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way we can remove all css properties with this?

Comment: I tried the first one and it works beautifully! For all the newbies who might not have known: css('attr','') is not the same as removing that attr!

Answer (score 7):

As a note, depending upon the property you may be able to set it to auto.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the best way I have found to do this when having to do complex jquery based styling, for Example, if you have a modal that you need to display but it needs to calculate page offsets to get the correct parameters those will need to go into the a jQuery("x").css({}) function.

So here is the setting of the styles, the output of variables that have computed based on various factors.

```
$(".modal").css({ border: "1px solid #ccc", padding: "3rem", position: "absolute", zIndex: 999, background: "#fff", top: "30", visibility: "visible"})
```

In order to clear those styles. rather than setting something like

```
$(".modal").css({ border: "", padding: "", position: "", zIndex: 0, background: "", top: "", visibility: ""})
```

The simple way would be

```
$(".modal").attr("style", "")
```

When jquery manipulates elements on the dom, the styles are written to the element in the "style" attribute as if you were writing the styles inline. All you have to do is to clear that attribute and the item should reset to its original styles

Hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Set the default value, for example:

$(this).css("height", "auto");

or in the case of other CSS features

$(this).css("height", "inherit");

Answer (score 4):

i have same prob too,
just remove the value

```
<script>
      $("#play").toggle(function(){$(this).css("background","url(player.png) -100px 0px no-repeat");},
      function(){$(this).css("background","");});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use classes (which you really should), the only way to accomplish what you want is by saving the changing styles first:

```
var oldFontSize = $(this).css("font-size");
var oldBackgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");

// set style
// do your thing

$(this).css("font-size",oldFontSize);
// etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the second solution of user147767

However, there is a typo here. It should be

> curCssName.toUpperCase().indexOf(cssName.toUpperCase()
>   + ':') < 0

not <= 0

I also changed this condition for:

> !curCssName.match(new RegExp(cssName +
>   "(-.+)?:"), "mi")

as sometimes we add a css property over jQuery, and it's added in a different way for different browsers (i.e. the border property will be added as "border" for Firefox, and "border-top", "border-bottom" etc for IE).

Answer (score 1):

Before adding a class you should check if it already had class with .hasClass() method

For your specific question. You should be putting your stuff in Cascading Stylesheet. It's best practice to separate design and functionality.

so the proposed solution of adding and removing class names is best practice.

however when you are manipulating elements you don't control of how they are rendered. removeAttr('style') is BEST way to remove all inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

I modified user147767's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206204/1250044) a bit to make it possible to use `strings`, `arrays` and `objects` as input:

```
/*!
 * jquery.removecss.js v0.2 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17196154/1250044
 * Remove multiple properties from an element in your DOM.
 *
 * @author Yannick Albert | #yckart
 * @param {Array|Object|String} css
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2013 Yannick Albert (http://yckart.com)
 * Licensed under the MIT license (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).
 * 2013/06/19
 **/

$.fn.removeCss = function (css) {
    var properties = [];
    var is = $.type(css);

    if (is === 'array') properties = css;
    if (is === 'object') for (var rule in css) properties.push(rule);
    if (is === 'string') properties = css.replace(/,$/, '').split(',');

    return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $.map(properties, function (prop) {
            $this.css(prop, '');
        });
    });
};

// set some styling
$('body').css({
    color: 'white',
    border: '1px solid red',
    background: 'red'
});

// remove it again
$('body').removeCss('background');
$('body').removeCss(['border']);
$('body').removeCss({
    color: 'white'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/88mJF/