# how to remove backgrount property of a div from css through jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove CSS from a Div using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955030/remove-css-from-a-div-using-jquery)

we can set backgroung-image property of a div like-

```
var src = "images/download_selected.png";
$('div#link1').css('background-image', 'url(' + src + ')');
```

**how can I remove backgrount-image or set background transparent?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('div#link1').css('background-image', 'none');
```

From here : http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_background-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

[Remove CSS from a Div using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955030/remove-css-from-a-div-using-jquery)