# remove unwanted styles from objects using jquery (or php)?

Tags: php, jquery, coding-style

I was wondering if there was any way of removing unwanted style attributes from objects (p, ul, li etc), as for some reason my client has decided to copy/paste information from word into a wysiwyg and doesn't bother removing the crap that comes along with it, I was wondering if jquery could do this?

Here's an example of the outputted code (which varies obviously depending on what they've copied/pasted from)

```
<ul style="list-style-type: disc;">
<li style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 21.0px; font: 12.0px 'Lucida Grande';">Residential Class 1/ New Buildings</li>
<li style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 21.0px; font: 12.0px 'Lucida Grande';">Residential Class 1/ Best Renovation</li>
<li style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 21.0px; font: 12.0px 'Lucida Grande';">Resorts, including apartments and aged care</li>
<li style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 21.0px; font: 12.0px 'Lucida Grande';">Public or Commercial Buildings</li>
<li style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 21.0px; font: 12.0px 'Lucida Grande';">Interior Fitout – Residential</li>
<li style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 21.0px; font: 12.0px 'Lucida Grande';">Interior Fitout – Commercial</li>
<li style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 21.0px; font: 12.0px 'Lucida Grande';">Outdoor Timber – Stand alone structures</li>
</ul>
```

Thoughts?

I've tried using strip_tags in php (and allow for p tags) but it brings the styles along with it.. even if this is possible in php that would be good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the style by :

```
$("#myelem").removeAttr("style");
```

If you want a specific styles to remove see [the answer of user147767](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955030/remove-css-from-a-div-using-jquery/1206204#1206204) in this topic:

[Remove CSS from a Div using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955030/remove-css-from-a-div-using-jquery)

He wrote a great function!

Comment: This will remove the entire style, not just an individual attribute as per the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$("ul").css("list-style-type", "");
$("li").css("margin", "");
$("li").css("line-height", "");
$("li").css("font", "");
```