# How to remove style one click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can i remove the style class applied to a textbox on the click event? I'm calling the textbox element using getElementsByName(). Here's my code:

```
<input id="userNameExists" name="popUpText" class="pop-upText" onclick="clearText(this);" />

function clearText(element)
{
                id = element.getAttribute("id");
                var textElement = document.getElementById(id);
                textElement.value = "";
                var element = document.getElementsByName("popUpText");
                var count = 0;
                for (count = 0; count < 2; count++) {
                    var id = element.item(count);
                    id.classname = "";
                }
}
```

In the above script, im not getting the id in the variable id. Right now the values are like "#inputTextBoxName". Please help.

Comment: to learn how to do this with jQuery check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955030/remove-css-from-a-div-using-jquery

Comment: The first two lines of your function are redundant: the `element` parameter to the function already contains a reference to the clicked element, so getting its id and then passing that to `getElementById()` just gets a reference to the same thing such that `element` and `textElement` point at the same input. Also I'd avoid (re)declaring a variable with the same name as the parameter. Finally `.classname` should be `.className` (capital N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `removeClass();`

you can manege your styling using `attr();`

exp:

```
$("#yourid").attr("style","float: right");
```

or remove class using

```
$("#yourid").removeClass("yourClass");
```

Comment: how can i reset the class when used with getElementsByName as follows element = document.getElementsByName("popUpText"); id=element.item(0) will return the id. To the variable 'id', how can i reset the class?

Comment: if you want to remove the class from variable id = $("#"+id).removeClass("yourClass");

Answer (score 0):

It is case sensitive so

```
id.className = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove the class from the textbox when you click on the textbox itself, that code is far, far longer than it needs to be.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="userNameExists" name="popUpText" class="pop-upText" onclick="clearText(this);" />
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function clearText(element) {
    element.className = '';
    element.value = '';
}
</script>
```

That said, inline event handlers (ie. declaring an `onclick` attribute on your HTML element) are a bad practice to get into.

Also, if you pass in a reference to an element, get its id, then call `document.getElementById()` with said id, you end up with two references to the same element. Yes, it should work, but totally pointless.