# Remove attr in input:style after click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can remove just `background-color: rgb(255, 196, 196);` in following select:style after click with jquery?

```
<input name="star" style="width: 60px; background-image: initial; background-attachment: initial; background-origin: initial; background-clip: initial; background-color: rgb(255, 196, 196); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function:

```
$('input[name="star"]').css({ backgroundColor : '' });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name=star]").click(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="star"]').click(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color':''});
});
```

you can read more here: [Remove CSS from a Div using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955030/remove-css-from-a-div-using-jquery)