# How to remove all CSS property inside a class, but don't remove class using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Remove all CSS property in class by  don't removing class using jQuery

For example :

```
    .ui-widget {
        font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif/*{ffDefault}*/;
        font-size: 1.1em/*{fsDefault}*/;
        left: 350px !important;
        top: 160px !important;
    }

    //To

    .ui-widget {
    }
```

Comment: So you want to modify the contents of a stylesheet with jQuery? I don't really understand what your last statement means.

Comment: @BoltClocK: Yes ,I need to modify using jQuery

Comment: from "by not removing class using jQuery" I understand you dont want to remove class like this -- $('.ui-widget').remove(); But you want to remove properties inside class so you can empty the css using jquery like this -- $('.ui-widget').css(' ');

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955030/remove-css-from-a-div-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to alter style properties, I would create two separate classes and use jQuery to toggle the classes of HTML elements.  That would seem to be more straightforward.

Comment: I use this style  inside an dialog box in jQuery .At first time  dialog opens and works nice according to new class style ,then I close dialog and reopen the dialog this time goes to old style.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, what Trott said.

Use something like this:

```
<script>
    $("p").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("removeStyle");
    });
</script>
```

That script causes the class to toggle when you click on a paragraph.  You can change the paragraph to be anything and it doesn't need to be a click function either.  The line with toggleClass is what's important there.

The toggleClass function will let you go back and forth between style and no-style.

Comment: @Philip: $('.ui-widget').toggleClass("ui-widget-new");  works fine.