# Deleting/removing function?

Tags: jquery

I'm having this little function which sets a div to position:fixed after a link is clicked.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#linktofreeze').click(function() {
        var ftop = $('#fixedbox').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
        var fleft = $('#fixedbox').offset().left;
        $('#fixedbox').css({position: 'fixed', left: fleft + 'px', top: ftop + 'px'});
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve now, is to make the whole thing backwards:
When a second link is clicked, the div's position shouldn't be 'fixed' anymore.

What is the best way to do this? Is there a way to delete/remove this function 'onClick' again?

To make it more clear, I uploaded the files on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hZX5h/72/

Would be great if anyone could help.
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery: Does this answer your question?

Comment: @möter: I think he's more concerned about removing the *effects* of the event handler rather than the event handler itself.

Comment: You will have to use a flag to toggle between what to do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955030/remove-css-from-a-div-using-jquery try this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset its **position** to `relative`

```
$("#linktounfreeze").click(function() {
  $('#fixedbox').css({position: 'relative'});  
  return false;
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVbGy/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want?
(Add this in the end of your js code):

```
$('#linktounfreeze').click(function () {
  $('#fixedbox').css({
    position: 'relative'
  });
return null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unbind method to achieve this:

```
$('#linktofreeze').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
```

Better method in jQuery 1.7+

```
$('#linktofreeze').off('click');
```