# Remove Selector CSS with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have CSS element selector, I want to remove it's CSS with the help of jQuery. How can I remove it CSS not the element **input[type="button"]**

> Issue is CSS file where it is written I cannot change as it is coming
>   from asp.net dll

```
input[type="button"] {
    min-width: 6em;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #444;
}
```

Comment: You want to remove this css-style?

Comment: Remove form the DOM/remove its styles/hide it?

Comment: Change the CSS to a class, then use `removeClass()` or `classList.remove()` in your JS

Comment: You have to use css specificity at this context. Create a new class with default styling properties and add it to the relevant elements during the runtime. You cannot remove a selector from a rendered CSS.

Comment: One suggestion can be to replace all the `input[type = "button"]` with `div` and style that div like a button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove CSS from a Div using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955030/remove-css-from-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am afraid of using this `all: initial` which used to set all css properties to initial.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").css('all', 'initial');
});
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myContainer">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="Submit">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="Reset">
</div>
```

Other wise you are suppose to change all css properties using jquery `css()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='button']").css({
    'background': 'initial',
    'color': 'initial'
  });
});
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myContainer">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="Submit">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="Reset">
</div>
```

Comment: This removes all button. I need to remove css

Comment: check the updated answer. am not sure about this will help or not!

Comment: No it did not works. It remove all other css class to :(

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to that styling and use `removeClass()` method... Check snippet below..

```js
$('input[type="button"]').removeClass('btn');
```

```css
.btn {
    min-width: 6em;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Button"/>
```

Comment: What I understand from the question, OP wants to remove the CSS associated with `input[type="button"]`, not the element itself

Comment: @Abhi just read question description, what OP wants `I have CSS element selector which I want to remove with the help of jQuery. How can I remove it input[type="button"]`

Comment: This removes all button. I need to remove css

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways to achieve this:

1. With pure CSS, just override the CSS associated with
   `input[type="button"]` with the help of a class and `!important`
2. Replace all the `input[type="button"]` elements with a div and
   have the dive styled like a button and work like a button

For example:

**jQuery**

```
var input_buttons = jQuery("input[type='button']");

jQuery.each(input_buttons, function(i, ele) {
  jQuery(ele).replaceWith("<div class='button' onclick='...'>Submit</div>")
});
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
  /* CSS to stylize the div to look like a button */
}
```

Comment: Issue is CSS file where it is written I cannot change as it is coming from asp.net dll

Comment: Then can you try the second way I suggested

Answer (score 0):

best way is use of `class` like this:

```
<input type="button" class="myButton">
```

And insert css codes to `.myButton` class like this:

```
.myButton {
    min-width: 6em;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #444;
}
```

so you can remove css code with this jquery code :

```
$('input[type=button]').removeClass('myButton');
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myButton').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('myButton');
    })
 })
```

```css
.myButton {
    min-width: 6em;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Segoe",Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<input type="button" class="myButton" value="Click Me!">
```